# When is the expected stable release date of Ubuntu Phone and Ubuntu Tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there an expected stable release date of Ubuntu Phone and Ubuntu Tablet?

If so, what are their dates?

Answer (score 16):

More robust versions of Ubuntu for Tablets will likely be available for the Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 tablets by the end of the year. However, Ubuntu tablets won't ship until the UI layer is folded into the fully unified Ubuntu 14.04 in the spring of 2014. Canonical expects to integrate a stable Ubuntu Phone with Ubuntu 13.10 ("Saucy Salamander") this October, making it available for Nexus 4 and Nexus Phone users, prior to a native Ubuntu-based phone launch in 1Q 2014.

You can see more informations at: http://www.linux.com/news/embedded-mobile/mobile-linux/702049-ubuntu-for-tablets-joins-canonicals-convergence-crusade

Answer (score 6):

Just confirmed by a developer over at the mailing lists. Ubuntu Touch 1.0 will be ready around the 17th of October.

```
To: ubuntu-phone@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
From: Loïc Minier <lool@xxxxxxxx>
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 17:20:37 +0200
In-reply-to: <20130912190101.GA27917@bee.dooz.org>

    Hi all!

Only four and a half weeks to go and phone 1.0 will be a reality!
Obviously we're all trying to finish or fix lots of things in the
remaining time, but that might include hard-to-track-down and painful
regressions.

We've got quite a bit of a backlog of things to land right now.  This
email is to ask everyone's kind cooperation in helping us land
everything that is ready while maintaining high quality for the images.

...

...

  Thanks for your help with this.
-- 
Loïc Minier
```

Source: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg04142.html

News article on the subject: http://www.paritynews.com/2013/09/19/2851/developer-confirms-canonical-ubuntu-touch-launch-date/

<sup>(Full disclosure: I am the author of the article and founder of ParityNews)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

From [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register)

> ## Find out when it’s here
>
> We are all excited about Ubuntu for phones, but it will take some time
>   to get into the marketplace. If you leave us your email and country
>   details, we will let you know when there is any news. We expect to
>   only email you a couple of times and promise not to spam you.
>
> **Your email: *_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register

<sub>last checked mid-February **2014**</sub>

Comment: Received no email inspite of apparent news of release here: http://www.ubuntu.com/phone

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is out there for sale (in Europe) already, released a few hours slash days ago:

- http://www.engadget.com/2015/02/06/ubuntu-phone-launch/
- http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/news/mobile-phone/3503217/ubuntu-phone-release-date-price-specs/
- http://www.bq.com/gb/products/aquaris-e4-5.html

> ### [The all-new BQ Aquaris E4.5](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone)
>
> - Slots for two micro-SIM cards so you can use your phone on more than one network
> - Dragontrail glass for scratch and impact resistance
> - 8 megapixel camera with autofocus and dual flash
> - Full HD (1080p) camera for super-sharp video recording
> - 8 GB internal memory with MicroSD slot for extra storage (up to 32GB)
> - Dimensions: 137 x 67 x 9 mm
> - Weight: 123g
>
> Only 169,90€
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu tablets and phones most likely wont be shipping until early 2014 when ubuntu v14.04 is released. There should be a stable version by october if you are an advanced user of a nexus 10 and know how to unlock it so that you can follow the directions to flash it to your tablet. I hope this helps. This information was all from Ubuntu's site about their plans.

Answer (score 0):

Shuttleworth said earlier in February that devices running Ubuntu Touch will actually ship in October, but that seems unlikely now given that we have had no announcements of that sort to date... unless he has a surprise in store for us!

More realistically, a first-time consumer-ready version (lets say Ubuntu Touch v1.0) should be ready in October 2013 (and released along with Ubuntu 13.10 desktop version). The version for tablets and the overall phone-tablet-PC convergence features are not expected to arrive until April 2014 (when Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for desktops is released).
All of the above is my conclusion based on currently available information as of early August 2013. :)