# What is the list of TABLETS able to run with Ubuntu-Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

In the official Ubuntu website I can found:

- the [list of Ubuntu **desktop** certified hardwares](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/)
- the [list of Ubuntu **server** certified hardwares](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/)

But no list of **tablets**!

In Ubuntu web site, I can found that there is the [Hardware **requirement**](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/operators-and-oems) for installing Ubuntu-Touch.
A good start, but a real list would be better, for example searching for anwsers in AskUbuntu I see [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/209898/32413) some tablet (Windows ones) can simply not run with Ubuntu "*due to secure keys in order to boot up it*", so I conclude that Hardware requirement is not enough.

---

I found a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/163755/32413) opened 1 year ago. But the answers to this old question were about installing Ubuntu **Desktop**.
**Is there anything new with [Ubuntu-Touch](https://askubuntu.com/q/282698/32413)?**

---

[image]

Comment: It is the same OS on both phones and tablets...

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 tablets in this [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Supported_devices_and_codenames)

- Nexus 7
  [image]
- Nexus 10 Manta
  [image]

Comment: Interesting doc that shows what "works" on the nexus's https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0ArLs7UPtu-hJdDZDNWliMmV1YUJ3Zk1pQlpDdGp4VFE&usp=sharing